# Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL on Vendors ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to run this query and it keeps on telling me ambiguous column name on VendorID need help

```
Select VendorID
     , VendorName
     , InvoiceNumber
     , InvoiceDate
     , InvoiceTotal 
  FROM Vendors
  JOIN Invoices
    ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.InvoiceID
```

Comment: I think you mean to join on `Invoices.VendorID`.

Comment: This query has a problem that is not going to be in any duplicate, I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

Just qualify all your column names, and you will never have this problem again.  I also think your `ON` conditions are wrong:

```
SELECT v.VendorID, v.VendorName, i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceDate, i.InvoiceTotal
FROM Vendors v JOIN
     Invoices i
     ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID;
-----------------------^
```

For completeness, I will note that you can fix this particular problem with the `USING` clause.  However, it is better just to write code defensively so queries don't generate errors.